# Python - Recursive word list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get make an **anagram algorithm**, but I'm stuck once I get to the recursive part. Let me know if anymore information is needed.

**My code:**

```
def ana_words(words, letter_count):
    """Return all the anagrams using the given letters and allowed words.

    - letter_count has 26 keys (one per lowercase letter),
      and each value is a non-negative integer.

    @type words: list[str]
    @type letter_count: dict[str, int]
    @rtype: list[str]
    """
    anagrams_list = []
    if not letter_count:
        return [""]

    for word in words:
        if not _within_letter_count(word, letter_count):
            continue

        new_letter_count = dict(letter_count)

        for char in word:
            new_letter_count[char] -= 1

        # recursive function
        var1 = ana_words(words[1:], new_letter_count)

        sorted_word = ''.join(word)

        for i in var1:
            sorted_word = ''.join([word, i])

        anagrams_list.append(sorted_word)

    return anagrams_list
```

Words is a list of words from a file, and letter count is a dictionary of characters (*already in lower case*). the list of words in words is also in lowercase already.

**Input:** print ana_words('dormitory')

**Output I'm getting:**

```
['dirtyroom', 'dotoi', 'doori', 'dormitory', 'drytoori', 'itorod', 'ortoidry', 'rodtoi', 'roomidry', 'rootidry', 'torodi']
```

**Output I want**:

```
['dirty room', 'dormitory', 'room dirty']
```

Link to word list: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlfWKzBlwHQKbPj9P_pyKdmPwpg

Comment: Is it a requirement (or a will) to write something recursive? Because it's really counter-intuitive for your objective.

Comment: @Rightleg I want to do it with recursion, because I'm trying to learn recursion.

Comment: How does `print anagrams('dormitory')` know about `dirty, dormitory, room`?

Comment: Also, you are excluding the space character, so there should be 27 keys in letter count, I believe

Comment: @cricket_007 the words, dirty and room are from a file with a bunch of words, the words are all lower case

Comment: Sure, I'm just wondering how you are calling this `ana_words` function initially and what `_within_letter_count` does. In other words, show a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry i meant to write `ana_words('dormitory')`, so the function is called directly. As for `_within_letter_count` it just checks if word can be made using letters in letter_count. I can upload the code if needed, but it won't help with the current function.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your words list it is hard to tell why it is including the 'wrong' entries. Trying with just

```
words = ['room','dirty','dormitory']
```

Returns the correct entries.

if you are wanting spaces between the words you need to change

```
sorted_word = ''.join([word, i])
```

to

```
sorted_word = ' '.join([word, i])
```

(Note the added space)

Incidentally, if you are wanting to solve this problem more efficiently then using a 'trie' data structure to store words can help (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: I've uploaded the link to the words, also thank you for the spaces. https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlfWKzBlwHQKbPj9P_pyKdmPwpg

Answer (score 0):

**Question errors:**

You are saying:

> Words is a list of words from a file, and letter count is a dictionary of characters (already in lower case). the list of words in words is also in lowercase already.

But you are actually calling the function in a different way:

> `print ana_words('dormitory')`

This is not right.

**Checking if a dictionaries values are all 0:**

`if not letter_count:` doesn't do what you expected. To check if a dictionary has all 0s you should do `if not any(letter_count.values()):` that first obtains the values, checks if any of them is different from 0 and then negates the answer.

**Joining words:**

`str.join(arg1)` method is not for joining 2 words, is for joining an iterable passed as arg1 by the string, in your case the string is an iterable of chars and you are joining by nothing so the result is the same word.

```
''.join('Hello')
>>> 'Hello'
```

The second time you use it the iterable is the list and it joins word with each of the elements of var1 that is actually a list of words so thats fine excluding the space you are missing here. The problem is you are not doing anything with sorted_words. You are just using the last time it appears. The `anagram_list.append(sorted_word)` should be inside the loop and the `sorted_word = ''.join(word)` should be deleted.

**Other errors:**

Aside from all this errors, you are never checking if the letter count gets to 0 to stop recursion.

Comment: Words is a list of words, not characters, `['dorm', 'hello' ...]`. When I do word in words, I'm calling each word, so words[0] is 'dorm' in this example. You use recursion on the new_letter_count. With every word, if the char is words the value of the key of new_letter_count is subtracted by 1. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @Theo Words should be as you said, but in your question you specify `print(ana_words('dormitory'))` what's an error. That is what Im trying to explain. I will edit my answer.